# Changing Template Header for Appendices

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, documentclass-writing

I am using a modified [BYU Thesis Template](http://www.physics.byu.edu/undergraduate/latex.aspx) for my thesis.

I want to be able to change the page header for the the appendices to read "Appendix A Data & Display" instead of "Chapter A Data & Display" where "Data & Display" is the name of one of my appendices.

Here is the relevant code from the class file:

```
% The fancyhdr package allows you to easily customize the page header.
% The settings below produce a nice, well separated header.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}
```

I suppose I should be using an if statement, but my appendices (in their individual tex files) start with `\chapter{Data \& Display}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
```

should be

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
```

to deal with the automatic change of name from "Cahpter" to "Appendix". Modify the page style in the preamble of your document:

```
\documentclass{BYUPhys}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\makeatletter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textbf{\thepage}}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp \ \thechapter \ \ #1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Regular Chapter}
\lipsum[1-40]
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix One}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If my documnent is report class, how can I use your code? I want to left is section of each chapter.